# Passing two models to the Authorize middleware (also called can)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-middleware

I am trying to pass two models to the `Authorize` middleware, used under the name `can`.

`routes/api.php`

```
Route::middleware('can:reach,profile,photo')->resource('users/{user}/profiles/{profile}/photos', 'PhotoController');
```

Then I try to retrieve arguments like so:

`app/Policies/PhotoPolicy.php`

```
public function reach(User $user, Profile $profile, Photo $photo)
{
    return $profile->id === $photo->profile->id;
}
```

But the middleware is totally ignored. I checked the definition of the middleware and I cannot see why this would not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the built-in laravel authorization system can deal with this.

Comment: Yes that is what I was afraid of. And then I took a look at the `handle` method definition of the `Authorize` middleware : `public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ability, ...$models)`. It potentially expects multiple models.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the middleware to the resource, not the opposite. Or, you can create a group.

Example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'can:reach,profile,photo'], function($router){
  $router->resource('users/{user}/profiles/{profile}/photos', 'PhotoController');
});
```